# I need to index a value in a list within a list- IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, list

I'm coding a simple turn based attack RPG that is LOTR themed. Each character has a list of actions (Offense/Defense) with each action having its own recursive list containing the action name, its power, how much mana it costs and a number I later use to calculate its success rate. Below is a small snippet of how I want to present the player with the actions he can perform based on if he has enough mana (action[2] for the third value in the list. Each turn I only want the player to see the actions that he has enough mana to perform. When I run the code in Pycharm it actually ends up printing the values that I need but it still closes the code with the indexing error. How can I fix this without changing the layout of the lists? Thank you!

```
action_list = [['Wrath of Mordor', 25, 20, 70],
                        ['Howl of the Ring Wraiths', 35, 25, 60],
                        ['Might of Morgoth', 40, 35, 45],
                        ['Pass']]

mana = 100

for action in action_list:
    if action[2] <= mana:
        print(action)
```

Comment: What is `action[2]` on the last iteration, when the first value is Pass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick work around for your issue, you are getting an index error because your last iteration only has one item where you are trying to access it's third (as Daniel commented).

```
for action in action_list:
    if action[0] == 'Pass':
        print('Pass') 
    elif action[2] <= mana:
        print(action)
```

Comment: This is inelegant construction, requiring the `continue`.  Remove that and use an `elif`.

Comment: Ok gotcha, is this just style or will there be cases where this is problematic?

Comment: Almost all style is derived from problematic cases.  This one is basic readability and maintainability: you've added a line of code to replace an existing language facility, designed for exactly this use case.  An irruption of the (otherwise) natural flow of your code is trickier to maintain as you expand the program.

Comment: Thank you this was really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate approach.  It uses a list comprehension and preserves the list of allowed actions.  I also reduced the mana to test the resource limit.

```
action_list = [['Wrath of Mordor', 25, 20, 70],
               ['Howl of the Ring Wraiths', 35, 25, 60],
               ['Might of Morgoth', 40, 35, 45],
               ['Pass']]

mana = 30

act_choice = [action for action in action_list
              if len(action) >= 2 and action[2] <= mana]

if act_choice:
    for action in act_choice:
        print(action[0], action[2])
else:
    print("Pass")
```

Output:

```
Wrath of Mordor 20
Howl of the Ring Wraiths 25
```

Comment: Thank you this was really helpful!